# XML Парсинг строки content:encoded

Tags: java, android, xml, парсер

Опираясь на статью :[XML парсинг](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/142-urok-79-xmlpullparser-parsim-xml.html) написал парсер. Но он отказывается видеть content:encoded. Подскажите как быть.

public class NewsXmlParser {

```
private ArrayList<NewsPars> products;


public NewsXmlParser(){
    products = new ArrayList<>();

}

public ArrayList<NewsPars> getProducts(){
    return  products;
}


public boolean parse(String xmlData){

    boolean status = true;
    NewsPars currentProduct = null;

    boolean inEntry = false;
    String textValue = "";


    try{
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(xmlData));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        boolean sales=false;
        while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            String tagName = xpp.getName();

            switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:


                    if("item".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)){
                        inEntry = true;
                        currentProduct = new NewsPars();
                      //  Log.d("Ryr",   xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "id"));
                    }


                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    textValue = xpp.getText();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:



                    if(inEntry){

                        if("item".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)){
                            products.add(currentProduct);
                            inEntry = false;                            

                        }
                        else if("guid".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)){
                            currentProduct.setGuid(Integer.parseInt(textValue));
                            values.put("guid", textValue);
                        }
                        else if("title".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)){
                            currentProduct.setTitle(textValue);
                            values.put("price", textValue);
                        }
                        else if("pubDate".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)){
                            currentProduct.setPubDate(textValue);
                            values.put("pubDate", textValue);
                        }
                        else if("description".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)){
                            currentProduct.setDescription(textValue);
                            values.put("description", textValue);
                        }
                        else if("content:encoded".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)){
                            currentProduct.setContentencoded(textValue);
                            values.put("content:encoded", textValue);
                        }
                        else if("linked".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)){
                            currentProduct.setLinked(textValue);
                            values.put("linked", textValue);
                        }



                    }
                    break;
                default:
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();

        }

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        status = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  status;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось банальным. Заменил "content:encoded" на "encoded"